# jQuery Full Screen Background moving when on menu

Tags: jquery, fullscreen

I'm currently building a Full-Screen gallery WP theme and I've noticed that when you try to select an image to view the background and scroll up and down with the mouse, this works as long as the image has been selected but I'm trying to make a scroll-free area (image menu) so that when you select a new image to view the background it doesn't jump around.

This is my `global.js`. I notice that if I add the `return false;` it stops scrolling but I lost the image change so i removed it.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".dropgallery a, #fp_thumbtoggle").removeAttr("title");

    $('#fp_thumbtoggle, .dropgallery img').click(function() {
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').toggleClass("active");

        if ($('#fp_thumbtoggle').hasClass('active')){
            $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'65px'});
        }else{
            $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'185px'});
        }
        $('.dropgallery').slideToggle('500');
        return false;
    });

 });
```

You can find my `gallery.js` [here](http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/fullthrottle/wp-content/themes/fullthrottle/js/gallery.js).

Comment: Didn't you just ask something like this?

Comment: Little similar, but I'm trying to make like a scroll free zone so the background doesn't move around when using the menu or slide down toggle. Any advice would be great.

Comment: What about using mouse event in your scroll-free zone and use stopPropagation

Comment: how would i go around using stopPropagation ?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
$('selector').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Explanation:**

Event handlers (whether jQuery or raw JavaScript) take a single parameter, an event. These event objects have all sorts of nifty things in them that make them useful, but many of these vary by browser. Fortunately stopPropagation is universal.

For your use case, you're probably having problems with the events bubbling up the stack. Say you have something like this:

- document (with click handler)

  - div (with click handler)

    - div (with click handler)

The event will be fired first on the bottom div, then once that execution has completed, it will bubble up. Each listener will get the notification until there are no more listeners.

In order to stop this bubbling, JavaScript (not jQuery) has given us a `stopPropagation` method on that event object. Calling this will tell the browser to cancel the bubble process.

Comment: I'm finding this impossible to get working is they any better examples that I could use for this ?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/)? I'm not sure what you mean by 'not working'. stopPropagation will prevent any other event handler from getting called. Where exactly are you having problems?